# Create different scene for different device

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

I think I can create different storyboards for different devices but I am wondering is there any way to create different scenes for different devices? There is just one scene which is quite complicated to be adaptive to the different screens by Size class.

I can create only one entry point in the storyboard, but is there a way I can swap the scene on the fly?

Answer (score 1):

The Size class is more deceptive than what you think. Its use is quite limited, so you can't easily change the layout between iPhone 5 & 6 for example.

Depending on what "changes" on your View you could create a class that loads different Nibs depending on the device it's being shown at.

By overriding both:

```
override init(frame: CGRect)
```

and

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
```

In where instead of loading a single nib for the view, you load the desired one based on the device you are targeting:

```
nib = UINib(nibName: "iPhone4Size", bundle: bundle)
```

This technique is used in UIDesignable explained here:

http://supereasyapps.com/blog/2014/12/15/create-an-ibdesignable-uiview-subclass-with-code-from-an-xib-file-in-xcode-6

However the "loading of a different nib per device" is not, that's just a simple "switch case" that returns a different Nib name.